# Unit memcached.service not found on Ubunto 20.04 when installing memcached

Tags: memcached, vultr

I'm trying to follow [these instructions on Vultr](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-memcached-from-source-on-ubuntu-20-04/) for Ubuntu 20.04 to install memcached, however when I get to the step `sudo make install`, the output is:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17/doc'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17/doc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17/doc'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17'
root@plesk:~/memcached-1.6.17# ./memcached --version
memcached 1.6.17
root@plesk:~/memcached-1.6.17# sudo make install
make  install-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17'
Making install in doc
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17/doc'
make  install-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17/doc'
make[4]: Entering directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17/doc'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/memcached/share/man/man1'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 memcached.1 '/usr/local/memcached/share/man/man1'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17/doc'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17/doc'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17'
make[3]: Entering directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/memcached/bin'
  /usr/bin/install -c memcached '/usr/local/memcached/bin'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/memcached/include/memcached'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 protocol_binary.h xxhash.h '/usr/local/memcached/include/memcached'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/memcached-1.6.17'
```

And then attempting to start memcached with:

```
sudo systemctl start memcached
```

results in `Failed to start memcached.service: Unit memcached.service not found.`

What am I missing here?

(Also Vultr instructs "Test if Memcached is active and running on TCP port 11211" by running `netstat -tulpn | grep :11211`--when I first tried to do this, I had to install netstat, but running this command does nothing.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed memcached from source, you will need to run the binary directly from the command line to start the service.

```
/usr/local/memcached/bin/memcached -d -m 64 -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11211
```